# Javafx - Can Images in a StackPane be offset and if so what am I doing Wrong?

Tags: java, image, javafx

I just have a very basic question, I am wondering what would be the best way to make a stack of cards where each are offset. In the code below I tried to use a StackPane, the problem is however that it doesn't seem to register the offset coordinates.

In the image below you will see that I tried to deal 2 cards to the dealer and to player1 and yes those are two different stacks (Note: I haven't taken the time to position them correctly yet, also the border around the table is temporary). I tried manually loading the cards and I get the same result, it doesn't offset the cards so it appears as though only one card is on the table:
[image]

```
public class PlayerTableCardPane extends Pane {
    // Data Fields
    ImageView[] cardBack;
    private int cardXOffset;
    private int cardHeight;
    private int cardCount;

    // StackPane for cards
    StackPane cardStack;

    /** Constructor */
    public PlayerTableCardPane() {
        this(50, 5);
    }

    /** Constructor for setting custom height */
    public PlayerTableCardPane(int cardHeight, int cardXOffset) {
        this.cardStack = new StackPane();
        this.cardBack = new ImageView[5];
        this.cardXOffset = cardXOffset;
        this.cardHeight = cardHeight;
        this.cardCount = 0;

        for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
            Image newImage = new Image("image/cardDownSm.png");
            ImageView setCardBack = new ImageView();
            setCardBack.setImage(newImage);
            setCardBack.setVisible(false);
            setCardBack.setFitHeight(cardHeight);
            setCardBack.setPreserveRatio(true);
            setCardBack.setSmooth(true);
            // Offset each card
            setCardBack.setX(index * cardXOffset);
            this.cardBack[index] = setCardBack;
        }

        this.cardStack.getChildren().addAll(this.cardBack);
        getChildren().add(this.cardStack);
    }

    /** Get cardXOffset */
    public int getCardXOffset() {
        return this.cardXOffset;
    }

    /** Set cardXOffset */
    public void setCardXOffset(int cardXOffset) {
        this.cardXOffset = cardXOffset;
    }

    /** Get cardCount */
    public int getCardCount() {
        return this.cardCount;
    }

    /** Set cardCount */
    public void setCardCount(int cardCount) {
        this.cardCount = cardCount;
    }

    /** Load cards into StackPane */
    public void loadCard() {
        if (cardCount == 0) {
            cardBack[0].setVisible(true);
        } else if (cardCount == 1) {
            cardBack[1].setVisible(true);
        } else if (cardCount == 2) {
            cardBack[2].setVisible(true);
        } else if (cardCount == 3) {
            cardBack[3].setVisible(true);
        } else if (cardCount == 4) {
            cardBack[4].setVisible(true);
        }
        this.cardCount++;
    }

    /** Hide last card() */
    public void hideLastCard() {
        if (cardCount == 4) {
            cardBack[4].setVisible(false);
        } else if (cardCount == 3) {
            cardBack[3].setVisible(false);
        } else if (cardCount == 2) {
            cardBack[2].setVisible(false);
        } else if (cardCount == 1) {
            cardBack[1].setVisible(false);
        } else if (cardCount == 0) {
            cardBack[0].setVisible(false);
        }
        this.cardCount--;
    }

    /** Replace card with FaceUp Image */
    public void setCardImg(ImageView card, int cardPos) {
        cardBack[cardPos].setImage(card.getImage());
    }
}
```

Comment: `StackPane`s center their contents. Try using a `Pane` instead.

Comment: Alright, thanks @James_D...I thought so but for some reason I was thinking you could still offset them, silly me. XD

Comment: AIUI it just ignores the layoutX and layoutY and positions them according to the `StackPane`'s alignment property

Comment: Ah, I see...I know it's a stupid question, I probably should have looked through a book...sorry for bothering y'all with it.

Comment: Thanks again @James_D, I basically removed the StackPane and added the cards with "getchildren().addAll(this.cardBack);"

Comment: Btw, I feel really stupid for even asking that. If y'all feel I should delete this let me know and I will

Comment: Actually, I don't think that's a stupid question at all... it's fairly counter-intuitive. You might actually be able to offset them in a `StackPane` using `setTranslateX(...)`, don't have time to test it.

Comment: Holy cow, you were right @James_D...Post that as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StackPane` lays out its child `Node`s according just to the `alignment` property of the `StackPane` itself: the `layoutX` and `layoutY` of the `Node` are basically ignored. The default value of the `alignment` property is `CENTER`. Your best solution here is just to use a `Pane` instead of a `StackPane`.

You could also potentially solve this by setting the `translateX` property of the images to be placed in the `StackPane`. However, note that such transforms are not included in layout calculations, so you introduce the possibility of pushing the cards out of the visible bounds of the `StackPane`.